# Displaying array values in jsp

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, web-applications

I have following two array in my code

```
List<Double> centralityList = (List<Double>) request
            .getAttribute("centralityList");

List<String> labelList = (List<String>) request
            .getAttribute("labelList");.
```

Now I have six string values and corresponding 6 double values of the string in these two array. My question is how to display them in tabular format in my JSP?Is this possible

For Example:

label list contains         [a,b,c,d,e]
centrality list contains-   [4,6,8,9,0]

So now I want to display output like:

```
label list   centrality list

  a                 4
  b                 6
  c                 8.
  .                 .
```

etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes of course you can. You can use scriplets but they are not recommended. Instead use JSTL.

Try this out:

Have this at top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And code for displaying data

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(centralityList) - 1}" var="index">
   <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${centralityList[index]}"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${labelList[index]}"/></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
    <%
   List<Double> centralityList = (List<Double>) request
            .getAttribute("centralityList");

   List<String> labelList = (List<String>) request
            .getAttribute("labelList");

    String myString="";
%>
<table>
<tr><td>
<%

    for(int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); i++)
    {
       out.println((String)labelList.get(i));
    }

    %>
</td><td>
<%

    for(int i = 0; i < centralityList.size(); i++)
    {
       out.println((double)centralityList.get(i));
    }

    %>
</td>
</table>
```

You can achieve this eaisly by using JSTL which is even more easy and far better way but as in your code I didn't find any evidence of using JSTL , so this is the way for now

Comment: I think using JSTL tags for these tasks is the correct approach rather using scriplets and hardcoading the logic.I prefer @Abu approach. Am I correct..please give reply

Comment: yes sure.I also want to suggest you to use JSTL but as you didn't mention anywhere that you are using JSTL so I gave you this example.Thats why at the end of the answer I suggest you to use JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL tags and iterate through this-

```
<c:forEach var="Array" items="userNames">

         // do something with the element
</c:forEach>
```

Use this in your jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: use this value as items as per your array name - "centralityList".

Comment: Inside the foreach you can print like this - <tr>
                    <td>${centrallylist}</td>
                </tr>