# Display arrays of String as table columns in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a `String activity[]=new String[2]` say `activity[0]=["sleeping"] and activity[1]=["eat","play"]` and another `String name[]=new String[2]` say  `name[0]="amit"` and `name[1]="sumit"` I have passed both string array to jsp page. Now I want to display these two strings in tabular manner say

[image]

how can I achieve it using jsp.

Comment: In jsp use table tag,name and hobby are th

Comment: How does `activity[1]` have two values?

Comment: @javaBeginner I want to know how it can be achieved using for loop <c:forEach></<c:forEach>

Comment: @peeskillet activity was List<String> which converted to string[]

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697456/displaying-array-values-in-jsp Also, consider handling a Map, instead of separate collections.

Comment: -1: `activity[1]`  cant be `["eat","play"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .jsp file do like this:

```
<%
        String[][] activityList=(String[][])request.getAttribute("activity");
        String[] nameList=(String[])request.getAttribute("name");

        out.print("<table border='1'>");
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<td>Name</td>");
        out.print("<td>Hobby</td>");
        out.print("</tr>");
        for(int i=0;i<activityList.length;i++){
            String [] a=activityList[i];
            for(String h:a){
                out.print("<tr>");
                out.print("<td>"+nameList[i]+"</td>");
                out.print("<td>"+h+"</td>");
                out.print("</tr>");
            }
        }
        out.print("</table>");
    %>
```