# Hibernate count for key and value

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have task to count books by genre. 
Example : genre1 - 5;

I don't know how to count?

```
public List<Integer> task4() {

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    String sql = "SELECT book.genre, COUNT(book.genre) AS counter FROM book book  GROUP BY genre";
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity(Book.class);
   // List<Integer> task4List = session.createQuery("SELECT book.genre, COUNT(book.genre) AS counter FROM book  GROUP BY genre")
    //        .list();

    List<Integer>  task4List = query.list();

    //Map<Integer,String> task4List  = (Map<counter,genre>)
    return task4List;

}
```

First time I was just try count genre without genre's name. And I have problem with this.
How correct count genre with or without genre?

Model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")

public class Book {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;


@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "published")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date published;

@Column(name = "genre")
private String genre;

@Column(name = "rating")
private int rating;
```

P.S. 
Every hint with criteria or hql will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String genre  = "SELECT book.genre FROM Book book  GROUP BY genre";
    SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(genre);
    List<String>  genreList = query.list();

    String count = "SELECT  COUNT(genre) AS counter FROM book book  GROUP BY genre";
    query= session.createSQLQuery(count);
    List<Integer>  countList = query.list();

   Map<String, Integer> task4List = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String genre : genreList) {
         task4List.put(genre ,countList.get(genreList.indexOf(genre)));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try this code

```
public void task4() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "SELECT genre, COUNT(1) FROM Book GROUP BY genre";
    Query query=session.createQuery(sql);
    List<Object[]>  task4List = query.list();
    for(Object[] o:task4List) {
        System.out.println("genre = "+o[0]+"   Count = "+o[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of printing, you can return task4List  object and set this object into request attribute then print in JSP. 

You can take the from this link [How to display array values in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697456/displaying-array-values-in-jsp)

Comment: could not execute query Column 'id' not found.  - that is when i run your code

Answer (score 0):

This SQL should work:

> select count(distinct(genre)) from book

You can also use Projections in the Hibernate Criterion API. Both count and distinct are Hibernate projections and Hibernate will generate the correct SQL based on the entity mapping.

Comment: Yeah, its work, but I need to genre name to. So what can i do?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I missed that. This is the correct scalar SQL: 
select count(genre), genre from book GROUP BY genre
You will still need to map this to some Object which provides some place to store the count and the genre string.  List<Integer> only provides a place to store a count.

Comment: Look at my answer on the question. I guess this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> task4() {

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    String genre  = "SELECT book.genre FROM Book book  GROUP BY genre";
    SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(genre);
    List<String>  genreList = query.list();

    String count = "SELECT  COUNT(genre) AS counter FROM book book  GROUP BY genre";
    query= session.createSQLQuery(count);
    List<Integer>  countList = query.list();

    Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> task4List = new Hashtable<List<String>, List<Integer>>();
    task4List.put(genreList,countList);

    return task4List;

}
```